# iterating over a list by a certain number

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following list:

```
['id-1213fsr53', 'WAITING', '54-81-24-40', 'world', 'id-343252sfsg', 'WAITING', '54-41-06-143', 'hello']
```

the list can be subdivided into tuples in the following format:

```
(id, status, ip-address, name)
```

So, in other to check the status, I need to iterate over that list by those 4 element tuples,
like:

```
for s in status:
   (id, status, ip-address, name) = s # (s is a 4 element list)
   # increment s by 4, and continue the loop
```

How can I achieve such behavior in `python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a method of grouping elements into groups from the [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) docs:

```
data = ['id-1213fsr53', 'WAITING', '54-81-24-40', 'world', 'id-343252sfsg', 'WAITING', '54-41-06-143', 'hello']
for s in zip(*[iter(data)]*4):
    (id, status, ip_address, name) = s
```

You can also perform the unpacking in the iteration:

```
for id, status, ip_address, name in zip(*[iter(data)]*4):
    # do something
```

Here is what that `zip()` call is doing that allows for this type of iteration:

```
>>> zip(*[iter(data)]*4)
[('id-1213fsr53', 'WAITING', '54-81-24-40', 'world'), ('id-343252sfsg', 'WAITING', '54-41-06-143', 'hello')]
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is with the `grouper` [`itertools` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

You can use this like:

```
for s in grouper(status, 4):
```

Note that you will have issues if you use `status` for both unpacking one of the tuple values and for the raw data.

Comment: Huh, never had seen the grouper before. I like that method better. Upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for index in range(0, len(status), 4):
    (id,status,ip-address,name) = s[index:index+4]
```

Comment: @aruisdante it is not.

Comment: Huh, you're right, I swear to god I just did this this morning and `list[0:99]` gave me the first 100 elements in the list, but apparently I'm crazy because I just did it in the terminal and it did not.